# How to open camera to scan QR code into Google Form field?

Tags: google-apps-script, camera, qr-code, google-forms

We use Google Forms to track entry into certain events. Staff and attendees enter their ID number which is handed out with a QR code.

I have been tasked with trying to figure out how we can access the iPads cameras (we use iPads for the forms) to scan attendees' QR codes and have their ID number from the code entered into the correct field in the form.

I believe we can use Google Apps Script somehow, but I am unsure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recent change to iphone dialogs for use with webapps provides me with access to a dialog that allows me to choose where a file upload comes from and one of the choices is the camera. I uploaded an image the app with the dialog showing.  I also included my html so that you can see that it's just a file upload. Perhaps this will help.

Image of App with Dialog:

[image]

And this is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function(){
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function(rObj){
          $('#dt').val(rObj.date);
        })
        .initForm();
        
      });
      function fileUploadJs(frmData) {
        var amt=$('#amt').val();
        var vndr=$('#vndr').val();
        var img=$('#img').val();
        if(!amt){
          window.alert('No amount provided');
          $('#amt').focus();
          return;
        }
        if(!vndr) {
          window.alert('No vendor provided');
          $('#vndr').focus();
          return;
        }
        if(!img) {
          window.alert('No image chosen');
          $('#img').focus();
        }
        document.getElementById('status').style.display ='inline';
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function(hl){
          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML=hl;
        })
        .uploadTheForm(frmData)
      }
      console.log('My Code');
    </script>
    <style>
      input,textarea{margin:5px 5px 5px 0;}
    </style>
  </head>
   <body>
    <h3 id="main-heading">Receipt Information</h3>
    <div id="formDiv">
      <form id="myForm">
        <br /><input type="date" name="date" id="dt"/>
        <br /><input type="number" name="amount" placeholder="Amount" id="amt" />
        <br /><input type="text" name="vendor" placeholder="Vendor" id="vndr"/>
        <br /><textarea name="notes" cols="40" rows="2" placeholder="NOTES"></textarea>
        <br/>Receipt Image
        <br /><input type="file" name="receipt" id="img" />
        <br /><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="fileUploadJs(this.parentNode)" />
      </form>
    </div>
  <div id="status" style="display: none">
  <!-- div will be filled with innerHTML after form submission. -->
  Uploading. Please wait...
  </div>  
</body>
</html>
```